# How can I negate this sentence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> If A is a subset of B then A and B are not disjoint sets.

Put it into Symbolic language:
$$\forall A, \forall B (A\subseteq B \Rightarrow A \cap B \neq \emptyset)$$

My attempt at negating is:
$$\exists A, \exists B (A\subseteq B \land A \cap B = \emptyset) $$

Is this correct? The negation confuses me a little because it doesn't look correct.

Comment: Looks OK, except I'd use $\emptyset$ instead of $0$.

Comment: Yes I used the empty set symbol, my MathJax is not very fluent haha

Comment: Then see if this statement makes sense given the above proposition:
"The proposition is true. Thus if the proposition $A \subseteq B$ is false then the proposition is trivially true because it is the result of an implication on which the antecedent is false. Supose that $A \subseteq B$ is true and prove that the same happens with the main proposition. Admit that A is a subset of B and so all elements of A are elements of B, A and B cannot be disjoint sets since the elements of A are common to the sets of A and B"

Comment: It makes perfect sense. If you wanted to give a counterexample to the quoted sentence, you can set $A=\varnothing$ and take any set for $B$. Why does this work as a counterexample? Because $A$ is a subset of $B$ but their intersection is empty.

Comment: Alright great, only one more doubt clouding my mind. A little change on the sentence to "Let there be A a subset of B" would result on a change of the quantifier from $\forall A, \forall B$ to $\exists A, \forall B$ am I correct?

Comment: There's not an "official" logical translation of the "let" idiom, so I'd need to see it in context. It often opens $\forall$-introduction arguments, so in a formal version of the revised phrasing I would actually expect neither $A$ nor $B$ to be quantified.